# Вывод данных из базы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Имею данный код:

```
    <?php

$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM works LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][] = $row;
}


echo "<ul class='clop'>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li class='work_title'>" . $name_work . "</li>" ;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li class='otdel'>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($exam_names as $exam_name){

            echo "<li class='bg_li'>".$exam_name['name_exam'] . " " . $exam_name['performer'] . " " . $exam_name['customer'] . " " . $exam_name['date_start'] . " " . $exam_name['date_end'] ." " . $exam_name['status'] ."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Как я могу вывести все поля из всех таблиц? Сейчас я вывожу только одно поле `name_work` из таблицы `works`, одно поле `name_otdel` из таблицы `otdel` и все поля из таблицы `exams`. Как вывести все поля из таблиц `otdel` и `works`? То есть как сформировать массив `data` и вывод для него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql_works = "SELECT w.*, o.*, e.* FROM works w LEFT JOIN otdel o ON w.id = o.id_type LEFT JOIN exam e ON o.id_otdel = e.id_otd";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($row)) {
        $data[$i][$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

вместо o.* и e.* вы должны перечислить нужные вам поля из таблиц `otdel` и `exam` - что-бы в результирующем массиве `$data` не было дублей типа `ID` или `NAME`

Comment: `mysql_query` и `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: @Visman: да есть такое. ТС использует mysql-драйвер, а код который я дал - mysqli.

Comment: @Борис а выводить потом так `row['поле1']`, `row['поле2']` и т.д. ?

Comment: @ArtemDoom: 
`for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) { echo $data[$i]["column"];}`